# flutter: 'Image' is not a subtype of type 'String' Error. What can I do?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm trying to change the background on my app depending on time of the, but I get an error. When I just hard code the specific background I want it works. My code is below.

The method at the end of my code checks if it's 'AM' or 'PM', then changes the background accordingly.
That method is called from inside the first container widget.

Note: I'm a newbie.

**CODE:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'GetLocation.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

void main() => runApp(WeatherApp());

class WeatherApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WeatherAppState createState() => _WeatherAppState();
}

class _WeatherAppState extends State<WeatherApp> {
  var apiKey = '5f10958d807d5c7e333ec2e54c4a5b16';
  var description;
  var temp;
  var city;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(image: AssetImage(displayBackground()
          ),
          ),
        ),
        child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          body: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 80),
                child: Text(
                  'Your Location',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                color: Colors.transparent,
                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50),
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      child: Text(
                        'City Name',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(width: 50),
                    Container(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.location_on,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Card(
                color: Colors.transparent,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: ListTile(
                    leading: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.wb_sunny,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                    title: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        'Temperature',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ),
                    subtitle: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        'Weather description',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  displayBackground(){
    var now = DateTime.now();
    final currentTime = DateFormat.jm().format(now);
    if(currentTime.contains('AM')){

      return Image.asset('images/BloodTime.jpg');
    }else if(currentTime.contains('PM')){
      return Image.asset('images/Sun.jpg');
    }
  }
}
```

**Error:**

```
Performing hot reload...
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following _TypeError was thrown building WeatherApp(dirty, state: _WeatherAppState#44045):
type 'Image' is not a subtype of type 'String'

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  WeatherApp file:///C:/Users/aldo0/Desktop/Learn_Flutter/my_weather_app/lib/main.dart:7:23
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      _WeatherAppState.build (package:com/main.dart:25:52)
#1      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4619:28)
#2      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4502:15)
#3      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4675:11)
#4      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4218:5)
...
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Reloaded 1 of 623 libraries in 459ms.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to just return string from displayBackground method.

```
   displayBackground(){
      var now = DateTime.now();
       final currentTime = DateFormat.jm().format(now);
           if(currentTime.contains('AM')){

               return 'images/BloodTime.jpg'; // change
            }else if(currentTime.contains('PM')){
                 return 'images/Sun.jpg'; // change
         }
    }
```

Comment: When I do what you do, I'm only getting a black screen wit text on it. No background image.

Edit: Your solution worked. Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you get any other errors? Did you make sure those images are added in pubspec.yaml file correctly?

Comment: Also make sure it is entry in any one if or else condition by printing in console.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: Quick question Viren, What would your approach be if you were to change the background based on specific time of the day/night? (e.g. if 06:00 am or after but before 10:00 am, display pic.jpg)

Comment: In this type of project this method i have to use very frequently, so i prefer to create a separate class and in that class i add this method. on top of that i prefer to compare time instead of checking am and pm in dateTime object.